# Send parameters via POST method in Android

Tags: android, post, http-post

I am developing an Android App

The below mentioned is the link .

"http://example.com.in/ai/abc?var="+**var**

where **var** is a variable where result has come.I want to  post the data available in the **var**  along with the link . I am new to android so I want to know How to do POST method in Android App.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");   . the link is .net based not php.  so how will it work ?  should i write something like this ?  [link] http://example.com.in/ai/abc?var.aspx [link]  and nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var", "12345"));

Comment: http://www.yoursite.com/script.php is an example, you may use your own URL.

Comment: Since it .NET  Is this how i should write ?   **new HttpPost("example.com.in/ai/abc?var.aspx");**   and nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var", "12345"));

Comment: You just use new HttpPost("example.com.in/ai/abc"); and it will work. Give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Android Volley Library** to post your data to your php script.Here is the example of Volley Request

```
//Declare the URL you want to send  
public static String YOUR_URL = "http://example.com.in/ai/abc?var=";

private void postDataToServer() {
    //volley request

                                                     //here you can choose your method,GET/POST,in this case is Post
    JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            YOUR_URL , null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //if send data success do something here
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //if having error to make request to server do something here
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //send your parameter here

            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("yourVariable", "var");


            return parameters;
        }

        //adding header to authenticate
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return  headers;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonReq);

}
```

You can look at [this tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrieve-data-from-mysql-database-in-android-using-volley/) to see how to post data from Android and get the data in your php script.

Comment: bro this Java..Android Volley Library

Comment: I get you a helpful link,reach about this 1st https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: This volley wont care what server side code you use,it will pass what it should pass to ur server .NET script.

Comment: sure..try it.let me know if works.remember get ur parameter u send from android at your .NET script.see what happen

Comment: i am getting lot of error ... where to call this whole function ?

Comment: you should call when your button is click or something else.Depends on your apps.whenever you do the network call

Comment: im trying to do it in a if loop but showing error.. some objects cant be resolved

Comment: Bro I think you should add the dependencies in your gradle 1st.see this link https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: add this `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'` in your gradle file